# Rank duplicate values by specific criteria

Tags: excel, duplicates, rank

I have a set of data (over 1 million records) with many instances of duplicative email addresses. I am looking to build a formula that prioritizes duplicate emails by other criteria, so I can identify a unique set of email addresses to update.

In this scenario, I am looking to rank by the following criteria:

1. Duplicate record has a Campaign ID
2. Duplicate record has the most recent modified date

If both of the above are true, I want the formula to return '1', otherwise return '0'

If criteria #1 does not exist, I want criteria #2 to take over (i.e. the 'excelisfun@gmail.com' example in the table below, I would expect the 6/5/22 modified date row to return a '1')

Where I am getting tripped up is that I want the rank formula to be controlled only by the duplicative emails in question. For instance, I do not want to compare all Most Recent Modified Dates against each other.

Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

Tried a formula similar to the below:

=IF(COUNTIFS(E:E,E2,I:I,"<="&I2)=COUNTIF(E:E,E2),1,0)

This works when you are only controlling for one email, but does not work against the dataset as a whole with all of the different emails mixed in. Also doesn't control for the second condition (the presence of a Campaign ID)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please (1) What language do you intend? (VBA? ... => specify; Excel formulas only => might want to migrate to (e.g. superuseer?): Stackoverflow ... "is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems". (2) Not sure what exactly you aim for: you basically say "prioritize for campaign ID, but ignore the presence if absent". Clarifying may increase the chance of an answer :-)

Comment: Sorry to ask, am I correct to assume that you have true consent from all the individuals to work with their aggregated personal (tracking?) data and taken reasonable measures to protect their data? And that a company that legitimately works with this amount of customer(?) personal data sure has some employee who can handle duplicates (and do more complicated stuff such as guarantee data protection), but is on holiday, and always does that in Excel (looks like?)? Or is homework?